Limit comparison test for infinite series
How do I know which sequence to use as $a_n$ and $b_n$?
I know that if $a_n, b_n > 0$ $$L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$$

If $L > 0$, then $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum b_n$ converges.
If $L=\infty$ and $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\sum b_n$ converges.
If $L=0$ and $\sum b_n$ converges, then $\sum a_n$ converges.

For example, I can't figure out this problem:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n+1}{4^n}$. My first thought was to use $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^n}$ but which one is $a_n$ and $b_n$?

This is the art of working with infinite series. There's no single, monolithic answer to your initial question.

So I guess just figuring out what would make the most sense to use?

It doesn't really matter which one you choose to be $a_n$ and which one is $b_n$. To see this try it both ways; you should get the same result.

Short answer.
It doesn't matter which is $a_n$ and which is $b_n$. The comparison test just compares the convergence of each of a pair of series.
Longer answer.
If you think about limits of positive quantities, the limit comparison test is symmetric with respect to $a_n \leftrightarrow b_n$ in the sense that, assuming that the ratios converge to something in $[0, \infty] = \{0\} \cup (0, \infty) \cup \{\infty\}$,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = L 
\quad\iff\quad
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n} = \frac1L, 
$$
where we interpret $\frac10 = \infty$ and $\frac1\infty = 0$.

Your example.
Say you choose $a_n = \dfrac{2n+1}{4^n}$ and $b_n = \dfrac{1}{4^n}$. Then,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} 
= \lim_{n \to \infty} (2n + 1) = \infty,
$$
which says two things:

If you know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ diverges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ does too.
If you know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ does too.

On the other hand, if we swap the roles so that $a_n = \dfrac{1}{4^n}$ and $b_n = \dfrac{2n+1}{4^n}$. Then,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} 
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n + 1} = 0,
$$
which again says the same two things, just with labels swapped:

If you know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ does too.
If you know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ does too.

Of course, none of these statements are particularly useful if we're using the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^n}$ converges (it does as a geometric series with common ratio $r = \frac14 < 1$) to determine that the other series converges.
What's going on?
The fact that the limit of the ratios is $0$ or $\infty$ (depending on which way you look at the ratio) means that in some sense the pure geometric series is infinitely smaller than the other series. This doesn't help to show that the other series converges, though. There are examples where this is the case and they both converge (e.g., $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$) and examples where this is the case and only the smaller one converges ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$).
What would work?
Assuming that you're trying to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n+1}{4^n}$ converges, then you're looking for something at least as big in the limit that also converges, i.e., some $b_n$ such that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} < \infty 
\quad\text{and}\quad
\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n < \infty.
$$
So, for example, if you knew that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{4^n}$ converges, then since
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 2, 
$$
noting that $2 < \infty$, then your series converges too.
Or if you knew that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{4^n}$ converges, then since
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 0, 
$$
noting that $0 < \infty$, then your series converges too.
Conversely, assuming that you were trying to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n+1}{4^n}$ diverges, then you're looking for something at least as small in the limit that also diverges, i.e., some $b_n$ such that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} > 0 
\quad\text{and}\quad
\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n = \infty.
$$
Of course, before you start messing around, you don't know which conclusion you're trying to reach. But these attempts can help you try to figure that out.
Can this work?
Is there another known convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ that we can compare to in the limit sense? Yes, but it won't work if it is geometric with the same common ratio $r = \tfrac14$. So, I leave you with this much narrower puzzle. Can you find a geometric series that converges, yet its terms are bigger (in the limiting sense) than the terms of your series?

The basic idea is as follows. Assume you want to show that $\sum a_n$ converges. Take $b_n$ such that: 1)$a_n\ll b_n$, 2)$\sum b_n$ converges and 3) the sequence $b_n$ is very simple (at least is simpler than $a_n$) so that you can prove item 2). Then you conclude that $\sum a_n$ converges.
Here is an example.
We have $a_n=(2n+1)/4^n$. Choose $b_n=1/2^n$. All items above hold.
We have $a_n/b_n\to 0$. As we know that $\sum b_n$ converges, we conclude that $\sum a_n$ converges as well.
